# DocuSign Integrator Key

Tags: docusign

I have generated Integrator key in demo DocuSign account, i am trying to publish it but due less than 20 successful transaction its failing in review.
Is there any way to test 20 + transaction for Integrator key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Postman (or any other API approach) to make 20+ calls (POST, PUT, GET, ...) to your demo account. For instance, creating some sample envelopes, getting status of some envelopes, creating a sample template, etc.

You could also run the same API call 20+ times, that would still work but I don't recommend it.

If you don't have any API calls ready. you might find a few samples in the Postman collection here:

- [DocuSign API in Postman](https://docusign.github.io/postman-esign-api-collection/)